# How can I transform this method in a recursive call?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, call, point

I have this method and I would to transform it in a recursive call.

```java
public double findDeltaL(Point[] pl) {
    double delta = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(FTCPPanel.WIDTH, 2) + Math.pow(FTCPPanel.HEIGHT, 2)); 
    double delta1;

    for (int j = 0; j < pl.length; j++) {
        for (int i = j + 1; i < pl.length; i++) {
            double x12 = pl[j].getX() - pl[i].getX();
            double y12 = pl[j].getY() - pl[i].getY();
            delta1 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x12, 2) + Math.pow(y12, 2));
            if (delta >= delta1) {
                delta = delta1;
                this.cp1[0] = pl[i];
                this.cp1[1] = pl[j];
            }
        }
    }
    return delta;
}
```

This method takes an array of points and calculates the minor distance between two points (delta).

And then put the pair of points in a new array (cp[]) that I will recall to print.

The pl[] is full of n random points, che cp1[] is an array with cp1.length=2, it contains the coordinates of the closest point.
This method calculate the distance between all the points in the array and then compares the delta1 and the delta (initialized to the max distance possible). the output is just delta, the minimum distance possible in pl[n].
Like if I have 3 points this is: P: [java.awt.Point[x=548,y=418], java.awt.Point[x=413,y=132], java.awt.Point[x=422,y=475]] Delta: 138.2931668593933 CP: [java.awt.Point[x=548,y=418], java.awt.Point[x=422,y=475]]

Comment: Please provide examples of input and expected output.  Also declare an `cp1` and any other values that are undefined or undeclared.

Comment: @WJS The pl[] is full of n random points, che cp1[] is an array with cp1.length=2, it contains the coordinates of the closest point. This method calculate the distance between all the points in the array and then compares the delta1 and the delta (initialized to the max distance possible). the output is just delta, the minimum distance possible in pl[n];

Comment: @WJS like if I have 3 points this is:
P: [java.awt.Point[x=548,y=418], java.awt.Point[x=413,y=132], java.awt.Point[x=422,y=475]]

Delta: 138.2931668593933

CP: [java.awt.Point[x=548,y=418], java.awt.Point[x=422,y=475]]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add details, instead of posting it in the comment section.

Comment: Why would you want to convert that to a recursive method? Non-recursive methods perform better than recursive ones.

Answer (score 0):

First, recursion isn't as efficient as your existing method.  So if anything, you would be de-optimizing you existing solution.  But if this is just an academic question, here is one solution that simply gets rid of the outer loop.

Call it like this.

```
ftc.findDeltaLRecurse(pl, 0, delta);
```

```
public double findDeltaLRecurse(Point[] pl, int next,
       double delta) {
    if (next < pl.length) {

       for (int i = next + 1; i < pl.length; i++) {

           double x12 = pl[next].getX() - pl[i].getX();
           double y12 = pl[next].getY() - pl[i].getY();

           double delta1 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x12, 2) + Math.pow(y12, 2));

           if (delta >= delta1) {
               delta = delta1;
               this.cp1[0] = pl[i];
               this.cp1[1] = pl[next];
               return findDeltaLRecurse(pl, next + 1,
                        delta);
           }
       }
   }
   return delta;
}
```

Note that the initial value of `delta` was computed outside the method and passed as an argument to avoid re-computing it upon each method call.

Answer (score 0):

```
public double findDeltaL(Point[] pl) {

    // not sure what you need to do if pl has only one point or if it null or empty array
    // so i assumed it has at least 2 element

    if (pl.length == 2) {
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(pl[1].getX() - pl[0].getX(), 2) +
                Math.pow(pl[1].getY() - pl[0].getY(), 2));
    } else {

        return findDeltaL(pl, 0);
    }

}

private double findDeltaL(Point[] pl, int currentIndex) {
    if (pl.length == currentIndex + 2) {
        return Math.min(minOfRow(pl, currentIndex));
        // confirm if it the correct order for cp1 and cp2 as i do not know what you do with it
        this.cp1[0] = pl[1];
        this.cp1[1] = pl[0];
    } else {
        return Math.min(minOfRow(pl, currentIndex), findDeltaL(pl, currentIndex + 1));
    }
}

private double minOfRow(Point[] pl, int currentIndex) {
    // delta could be defined as static (maybe final too) field of your class
   // minOFRow could also defined recursive in same way but you need to keep track of index of the current column on the current row also 

    double delta = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(FTCPPanel.WIDTH, 2) + Math.pow(FTCPPanel.HEIGHT, 2));
    double delta1;
    for (int i = currentIndex + 1; i < pl.length; i++) {

        double x12 = pl[currentIndex].getX() - pl[i].getX();
        double y12 = pl[currentIndex].getY() - pl[i].getY();

        delta1 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x12, 2) + Math.pow(y12, 2));

        if (delta >= delta1) {

            delta = delta1;
            this.cp1[0] = pl[i];
            this.cp1[1] = pl[currentIndex];
        }
    }
    return delta;
}
```